# iPhone - Changing values for keys in array of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm receiving some json data from server. It has array of dictionaries.
Each dictionary has keys X,Y,W and H. All are float values
Is there any way to change X value to X/2, Y value to Y/2, W value to W/2 and H value to H/2.

I can do it iterating through all the dictionaries. But is there any simple code that changes all values of X to X/2 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Tried fast enumeration?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html

Comment: I already mentioned that I don't want to iterate through all the dictionaries. For getting the values in array of dictionaries, we can use something like "valueForKeyPath". Similarly is there any method that sets the values?